# Create PDF from Merge document via ASP C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, merge

Okay, here is what i want to do..

A user will run a query and return 3 pieces of data (really more but for this example lets say 3.. such as name, city, state).

The user will then be prompted with a list of 1 or more documents that are basically word merge documents.  Does not have to be word but needs to be something standard.

Once they pic the document, we need to merge the data with the document and would then like to have a PDF displayed back to the user so they can print or save.

So, looking for ideas on what would be a suggested format to store the merge documents in as well as how to do the merge and create the PDF via ASP C#.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

firstly ... stop thinking "doc" as standard cause .. it is not.

PDF is much more standard than doc and using any online viewer it is easy to provide access to it's content

now...

for manipulating PDF files fore free u have a very nice C# Library called [iTextSharp](http://csharp-source.net/open-source/pdf-libraries/itextsharp)

Comment: Thanks for this and it may prove to be useful.  However, as I stated, I am working with a list of documents.  The user will be able to upload the merge docs.  I am not sure I can require everyone to upload them as PDF. I suppose I can convert them to PDF and then use the library mentioned to combine the template pdf with the new data.  Thoughts?

Comment: u should do exactly that! get all documents into a multiple pages PDF document, manipulate them, and add to your Document folder in the server giving the user the ability to share the document by link or using an online viewer ....